# PHP Array into array - error

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm trying to add an array into an other array at a specific key. But I have this message :

> array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

I don't understand because in the else I create the array.

```
$key = $this->input->get('vente');
if(array_key_exists($key,$this->session->userdata('panier'))){
    array_push($this->session->userdata('panier')[$key],$toAdd);
}else{
    $this->session->userdata('panier')[$key] = array();
    array_push($this->session->userdata('panier')[$key],$toAdd);
}
```

Comment: Thanks arkascha, but I want put the array at this index. Not at the end of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->session->userdata` return an array but you can't modify it directly. Try this :

```
<?php 
// Storing the session item in a var
$panier = $this->session->userdata('panier');

// $this->session->userdata return null when the item doesn't exist, so we have to check it
if (empty($panier)) $panier = array();

$key = $this->input->get('vente');

if( array_key_exists($key, $panier) ) {
    array_push($panier[$key], $toAdd);
} else {
    $this->session->userdata('panier')[$key] = array();
    array_push($panier[$key], $toAdd);
}

// Then, we set the var in session again !
$this->session->set_userdata('panier', $panier);
```

Don't hesitate if you need more explanations.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gwendal. I didn't think that I can't modify it directly. You save my night ;)

Comment: Ca me fait plaisir @RomainCaron :)